# GoogleFit wasn't able to connect, so the request failed-Android

Tags: android, service, google-fit

I have the following code where it does two main things.

1. It connects to google play services.
2. Inside the onConnected() method  a service is started, by calling the startService(...) method.

When I run the program I get the following log message.

```
Connected!!!
Fit wasn't able to connect, so the request failed.
GoogleFitService destroyed.
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String TAG = "GoogleFitService";
    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;

    private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
    private boolean authInProgress = false;

    private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildFitnessClient();
    }

    private void buildFitnessClient() {
        // Create the Google API Client
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                            // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                            // Put application specific code here.
                            Intent service = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                    GoogleFitService.class);

                            service.putExtra(GoogleFitService.SERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE,
                                    GoogleFitService.TYPE_REQUEST_CONNECTION);
                            startService(service);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                        new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                            // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Cause: " + result.toString());
                                if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                    // Show the localized error dialog

                                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), MainActivity.this, 0).show();
                                    return;
                                }

                                if (!authInProgress) {
                                    try {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                                        authInProgress = true;

                                        result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect to the Fitness API
        Log.i(TAG, "Connecting...");
        mClient.connect();
        Intent service = new Intent(this, GoogleFitService.class);
        service.putExtra(GoogleFitService.SERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE, GoogleFitService.TYPE_REQUEST_CONNECTION);
        startService(service);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mClient.isConnected()) {
            mClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
            authInProgress = false;

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
                if (!mClient.isConnecting() && !mClient.isConnected()) {
                    mClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
    }

}
```

And the second class is basically an Intent service. Maybe the mistake is here.

```
public class GoogleFitService extends IntentService {

    public static final String TAG = "GoogleFitService";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiFitnessClient;
    private boolean mTryingToConnect = false;

    public static final String SERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE = "requestType";
    public static final int TYPE_GET_STEP_TODAY_DATA = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_REQUEST_CONNECTION = 2;

    public static final String HISTORY_INTENT = "fitHistory";
    public static final String HISTORY_EXTRA_STEPS_TODAY = "stepsToday";

    public static final String FIT_NOTIFY_INTENT = "fitStatusUpdateIntent";
    public static final String FIT_EXTRA_CONNECTION_MESSAGE =
            "fitFirstConnection";
    public static final String FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_STATUS_CODE =
            "fitExtraFailedStatusCode";
    public static final String FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_INTENT =
            "fitExtraFailedIntent";

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleFitService destroyed");
        if (mGoogleApiFitnessClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconecting Google Fit.");
            mGoogleApiFitnessClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildFitnessClient();
        Log.d(TAG, "GoogleFitService created");
    }

    public GoogleFitService() {
        super("GoogleFitService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        //Get the request type
        int type = intent.getIntExtra(SERVICE_REQUEST_TYPE, 1);

        //block until google fit connects.  Give up after 10 seconds.
        if (!mGoogleApiFitnessClient.isConnected()) {
            mTryingToConnect = true;
            mGoogleApiFitnessClient.connect();

            //Wait until the service either connects or fails to connect
            while (mTryingToConnect) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100, 0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        if (mGoogleApiFitnessClient.isConnected()) {
            if (type == TYPE_GET_STEP_TODAY_DATA) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Requesting steps from Google Fit");
                getStepsToday();
                Log.d(TAG, "Fit update complete.  Allowing Android to destroy 
                        the service.");
            } else if (type == TYPE_REQUEST_CONNECTION) {

            }
        } else {
            //Not connected
            Log.w(TAG, "Fit wasn't able to connect, so the request failed.");
        }
    }

    private void getStepsToday() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

        DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiFitnessClient,
                        readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        DataSet stepData =
                dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);

        int totalSteps = 0;

        for (DataPoint dp : stepData.getDataPoints()) {
            for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                int steps = dp.getValue(field).asInt();

                totalSteps += steps;

            }
        }

        publishTodaysStepData(totalSteps);
    }

    private void publishTodaysStepData(int totalSteps) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HISTORY_INTENT);
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra(HISTORY_EXTRA_STEPS_TODAY, totalSteps);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void buildFitnessClient() {
        // Create the Google API Client
        mGoogleApiFitnessClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                        new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {

                            @Override
                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit connected.");
                                mTryingToConnect = false;
                                Log.d(TAG, "Notifying the UI that we're 
                                        connected.");
                                        notifyUiFitConnected();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at 
                                some point,

                                        mTryingToConnect = false;
                                if (i ==
                                        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit Connection lost.  
                                            Cause:Network Lost.");
                                } else if (i ==
                                        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit Connection lost.    
                                            Reason:Service Disconnected ");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                        new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                            // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult
                                                                   result) {
                                mTryingToConnect = false;
                                notifyUiFailedConnection(result);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .build();
    }

    private void notifyUiFitConnected() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FIT_NOTIFY_INTENT);
        intent.putExtra(FIT_EXTRA_CONNECTION_MESSAGE,
                FIT_EXTRA_CONNECTION_MESSAGE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void notifyUiFailedConnection(ConnectionResult result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FIT_NOTIFY_INTENT);
        intent.putExtra(FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_STATUS_CODE,
                result.getErrorCode());
        intent.putExtra(FIT_EXTRA_NOTIFY_FAILED_INTENT, result.getResolution());
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what might went wrong? Thanks, Theo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access those detail from fit only when it connected .And Try this

```
public void buildFitnessClient() {
    fitnessClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SESSIONS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            ReferenceWrapper.getInstance(context).setApiClient(fitnessClient);
                            ((OnClientConnectListener) context).onclientConnected();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                        }
                    })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                    new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(
                                ConnectionResult result) {
                            if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                                        result.getErrorCode(), context, 0)
                                        .show();
                                return;
                            }
                            if (!authInProgress) {
                                try {
                                    authInProgress = true;
                                    result.startResolutionForResult(
                                            context,
                                            KeyConstant.REQUEST_OAUTH);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }).build();
}
```

And at first you need to register your application on google api console . Generate an outh2 client id from there and enable fitness api . Search for fitness Api in api Dashboard , and enable it.. And override OnActivityresult 
in your Activity .

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == KeyConstant.REQUEST_OAUTH) {
         fitnessHelper.setAuthInProgress(false);
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             if (!fitnessHelper.isConnecting() && !fitnessHelper.isConnected()) {
                 fitnessHelper.connect();
             }
         }
     }
}
```